# Use only selected regular categories for a Custom post form

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

There's a way to use only some of regular categories for a Custom post form? 
Until now i was able to use ALL categories of the regular post type. But i want only a few of them to the custom post...

For example, i have 10 categories , and for the custom post type, i want to use only 4. (or a parent category with all their childs?)

Comment: Do you mean filter out the Categories metabox in the post creation/editing page of WP admin?

Comment: I need to use only some categories from the regular categories list, inside my custom post type.

If i create categories just for the custom post type, it is not showed in my excrept.

Example:

Normal posts:

Title
Text resume
categorie : (list of selected categories)

Custom Post:

Title
Text resume
categorie : (list of selected categories) (if i use custom categories, it doesn't shoews it here. Shows only if i use the regular)